# Git merge conflict

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am using bitbucket, and I have a merge conflict at one of the files in the branch I made a pull request for. 
When I do git status locally on the branch, I don't get any conflicts, I have pulled from the remote branch, and tried to do new commits, but I still get merge conflicts for the same file.
I have also tried with:

```
git checkout --ours -- src/js/services/article.js
git add src/js/services/article.js
git commit -m"Merged conflict"
```

But I get:

> Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/feature/publicArticle'. nothing
>   to commit, working directory clean

How can I fix that?

Comment: First of all, in the set of commands you've put you're trying to add a file that is already in the repository so there is no change by that action so it stays up-to-date. About the pull request issue, locally you don't perform any merge action so you don't have any conflict. I suggest that you'll read more about git merge in order to understand it better.

Comment: Why are you not pushing back to the feature branch?

Comment: I solved it and have written that I did push it to the remote branch in update part of my question

Comment: Please [don't edit the answer into your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262807/2747593). Instead, please [accept the answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that helped you the most. (If you found the answer yourself, you can even [self answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it if anyone needs it, by following the tutorial on [Atlassian](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/resolve-merge-conflicts-704414003.html).

From the local branch `feature/publicArticle`, I have done:

```
git merge origin feature/publicArticle
```

Then, I have fixed the conflict in the file, and then run:

```
git add src/js/services/article.js
git commit -m"Resolving conflicts"
```

After that pushed to the remote branch.